# Invalid operation at current cursor position. (Java Databases)

Tags: java, mysql, database, netbeans

I am running the following code to get data from database..

```
public String getCurrentSeason(String leagueName)
{
    String qry = "Select * from KHAN.LeagueSeason where league_name = '"+leagueName+"'       AND end_Date IS NULL";
        try{
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(qry);

            if(rs.next());
            {
                String s = rs.getString(1);
                return s;
            }
        }
        catch(SQLException err)
        {
            System.out.println(err.getMessage());
            System.exit(0);
        }
    return "";
}
```

Although I'm using rs.next() but still it gives an error "Invalid operation at current cursor position.". Can somebody point out the error. I'm a beginner to java programming. Assuming connection and all other thing were intialized in the class constructor

Comment: Instead of `System.out.println(err.getMessage())` use `err.printStackTrace()` and post the results

Comment: Does `if(rs.next());` really have semicolon at end??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would happen if you give a `leagueName` that does not exist as a parameter.

The problem is the semicolon after the if statement - since empty statements are legal in Java, you've actually implemented the following logic: If the `ResultSet` has another element, do nothing. Afterwards, whether you did nothing or not (which is kind of meaningless, of course), you open another block, and attempt to retrieve a string from that `ResultSet`. If it were empty, you'd get the error you describe.

To make a long story short - lose the semicolon after the `if`, and you should be fine:

```
public String getCurrentSeason(String leagueName)
{
    String qry = "Select * from KHAN.LeagueSeason where league_name = '"+leagueName+"'       AND end_Date IS NULL";
    try{
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(qry);

        if(rs.next()) // note: no semicolon here
        {
            String s = rs.getString(1);
            return s;
        }
    }
    catch(SQLException err)
    {
        System.out.println(err.getMessage());
        System.exit(0);
    }
    return "";
}
```